# Efficient way for checking number 3^x * 5^y

Tags: python, for-loop, primes, exponent

I want to check if number, based on lower and upper bound, has prime divisors only 3 and 5 and number should be multiplication of power of 3 and power of 5. My current solution is this. I want to optimize it, since checking powers with for loops isn't good way in my opinion. Thanks in advance.

```
def checkNum(x):
    for i in range(1,50):
        for j in range(1,50):
            return x == (3**i) * (5**j)


def printResult(l, r):
    for i in range(l,r):
        if checkNum(i):
            print(i)
```

Based on comments I think this is the best way:

```
def checkNum(x):
    while x%3==0:
        x = x //3
    while x%5==0:
        x = x//5
    return x==1
```

Comment: Can you think of a way to do it with repeated division/modulo instead? How would you solve the problem by hand normally?

Comment: Repeated divide by 3 for as long as the number is divisible by 3.  Repeated divide by 5 for as long as the number is divisible by 5.  Are you left with 1?

Comment: @FrankYellin so this is what you meant?
def checkNum(x):
    while x%3==0:
        x = x //3
    while x%5==0:
        x = x//5
    return x==1

Comment: @FrankYellin that may be a more efficient loop, but it's still a loop.

Comment: Your test for `if i%3==0 and i%5==0:` will exclude some candidates where `x` or `y` are zero.  Consider `i=9` for example.

Comment: An unconditional `return` in a loop means that the loop is iterated only once. The first `checkNum(x):` does nothing more than `return x == (3**1) * (5**1)`

Comment: As a hint for @MarkRansom 's comment, note that the condition is always false for numbers smaller than the LCM of the two numbers, with  `x, y ≠ 0`.

Comment: @MarkRansom  I realized and edited, thanks for pointing that out. What would you suggest for more optimized solution without loops?

Comment: @MarkRansom:   My code has a loop, but not the sort of loop of the original code, where it is checking 2500 possibilities.

Comment: @FrankYellin I did admit that your loop was more efficient.  I can't help feeling like there's a math trick that would make this super simple, but I can't think what it would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to optimize it, since checking powers with for loops isn't good
> way in my opinion.

Over a range of random numbers, we improve its speed by doing:

```
def checkNum0(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:  # eliminate half the numbers in one test!
        return False

    while x % 15 == 0:  # speed up the process
        x = x // 15

    while x % 5 == 0:
        x = x // 5

    while x % 3 == 0:
        x = x // 3

    return x == 1
```

Or we can use a nested loop and combine both divisions into one:

```
def checkNum(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:  # eliminate half the numbers in one test!
        return False

    for divisor in (15, 5, 3):
        while (quotient_remainder := divmod(x, divisor))[1] == 0:
            x = quotient_remainder[0]

    return x == 1
```